# Why does this code give an "Index was outside the bounds of the array" error?

Tags: c#

This code should basically split the user input into its component letters and then output the 1st, 3rd and 5th letter in the array

```
bool greater = false;
Console.WriteLine("Enter your name: ");
string userName3 = Console.ReadLine();
while (greater = false)
{
   if (userName3.Length >= 5)
   {
      greater = true;
   }
   else
   {
      Console.WriteLine("The name must be 5 characters or more");
   }
}
string[] userNameArr = userName3.Split();
Console.WriteLine(userNameArr[0] + " " + userNameArr[2] + " " + userNameArr[4]);
```

When I run the last line causes an error saying

> Index was outside the bounds of the array

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you please provide us input where you are getting this error

Comment: If, for example I enter "Warren" or indeed any input greater than 5 characters I get the IndexOutOfRange error

Comment: strings are by default immutable char arrays, you do not need to split them further

Answer (score 3):

`Split()` doesn't split into `char` it splits by detecting and spliting by WhiteSpace characters into a array of strings.

If you want to get the characters, access the input string by index `char firstChar = userName3[0];`

```
Console.WriteLine(userName3[0] + " " + userName3[2] + " " + userName3[4]);
```

instead of

```
string[] userNameArr = userName3.Split();
Console.WriteLine(userNameArr[0] + " " + userNameArr[2] + " " + userNameArr[4]);
```

---

Sidenote:
replace  `while (greater = false)` with `while (!greater)` or `while (greater == false)` since you want to do a comparison instead of a assingment

Comment: Had to check MSDN if there even is a split without arguments. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @downvoter care to comment?

Comment: I guess hate for answers on closed questions (or about to be closed). All answers got a downvote not just yours.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
bool greater = false;
while (greater == false)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Enter your name: ");
   string userName3 = Console.ReadLine();
   if (userName3.Length >= 5)
   {
      greater = true;
   }
   else
   {
      Console.WriteLine("The name must be 5 characters or more");
   }
}
string[] userNameArr = userName3.Split();
Console.WriteLine(userNameArr[0] + " " + userNameArr[2] + " " + userNameArr[4]);
```

The line:

```
while (greater = false)
```

Actually assigns false to greater, meaning you will never leave the loop.  Further, you need the `ReadLine` inside the loop so that the user will be prompted again

Answer (score 0):

**String is array of char, so to get specific character use indexing instead of `split()`**

for e.g. To get 5 letter from string use `userNameArr[4]`.

This can be correct way to read characters from string

```
    using System;

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            bool greater = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your name: ");
            string userName3 = Console.ReadLine();
            while (greater == false)
                {
                    if (userName3.Length >= 5)
                        {
                            greater = true;
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("The name must be 5 characters or more");
                        }
                }
//Indexing to string is used to get letters from string
                Console.WriteLine(userName3[0] + " " + userName3[2] + " " + userName3[4]);
        }
    }
```

Implemenation: [DotNetFiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QGfWmv)

Answer (score 0):

`userName3.Split()` splits the user name on spaces by default, so if username is `phuzi` then splitting will result in an array with a single item `["phuzi"]` then only `userNameArr[0]` is valid. Any attempt to acces anything else will result in the error you're seeing

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the array does not contain this index.
The line

```
string[] userNameArr = userName3.Split();
```

You want to split by what ?